# Add line to all htaccess files in www directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am having some odd traffic to the xmlrpc.php files hosted by the wordpress sites on my server. Instead of opening each htaccess file to add a deny rule, is there an easy way to echo or insert the line into all htaccess files in the www directory?

Comment: Yeah you need to do some scripting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into a file at root of all your vhosts and name the file htaccess_ins_deny_xmlrpc

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
  Order Allow,Deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Now, alongside that file, create a bash script:

```
for htfile in `find . -name .htaccess`
do
   cp "$htfile" "$htfile.bak"
   cat "htaccess_ins_deny_xmlrpc" >> "$htfile"
done
```

This will check all vhosts for the .htaccess file. If the .htaccess file is found, this will make a backup and append the rule.

Comment: thanks that is perfect, i tweaked the script a bit, i am learning bash and should have thought about find